# Moment JS isBefore return wrong result

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm having an issue with moment js library. the function isBefore sometimes returns the wrong result. Below code should return true, not false value.

```js
var clockIn = moment('1/5/2018 12:15 AM');
var startBreak = moment('1/5/2018 11:00 AM');

if(startBreak.isBefore(clockIn)){
  console.log('isBefore');
}else{
  console.log('isAfter');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Please advise.

Comment: this looks correct.  11am IS AFTER 12:15am.

Answer (score 4):

12:15 AM is before 11:00 AM perhaps you probably mean to be using 12:15 PM

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the right result, as `12:15 AM` is parsed as `00:15`, so `startBreak` (`11:00`) **is after** `clockIn` (`00:15`).

Anyway since your input is not in ISO 8601 recognized format, neither in RFC 2822 format, you have to use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

`D` stands for Day of month, `M` stands for month number, `YYYY` stands for 4 digit year, `hh` stands for `1..12` hour, `mm` stands for minutes and `A` stands for `AM`/`PM`.

Your current code throws *Deprecation Warning* and the message in the console points to [JS Date Construction](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/) guide.

Here a live sample:

```js
var clockIn = moment('1/5/2018 12:15 AM', 'D/M/YYYY hh:mm A');
var startBreak = moment('1/5/2018 11:00 AM', 'D/M/YYYY hh:mm A');

console.log('clockIn: ' + clockIn.format() + ' ' + clockIn.valueOf());
console.log('startBreak: ' + startBreak.format() + ' ' + startBreak.valueOf());

if(startBreak.isBefore(clockIn)){
  console.log('isBefore');
}else{
  console.log('isAfter');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```